# Having an error in Math Game in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math

I have made a math game program below, but it does not work when Start button is pressed... an error with message on the conversion area(where p,q,r are shown); 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."
How can I revise my code?

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.Next(0, 100);
        int b = random.Next(0, 100);
        int c = random.Next(0, 100);
        int d = random.Next(0, 100);
        int f = random.Next(0, 100);
        int g = random.Next(0, 100);
        labelOne.Content = "1." + a + " + " + b + " = ";
        labelTwo.Content = "2." + c + " - " + d + " = ";
        labelThree.Content = "3." + f + " * " + g + " = ";
        int score = 0;
        int p = int.Parse(textBoxOne.Text);
        int q = int.Parse(textBoxTwo.Text);
        int r = int.Parse(textBoxThree.Text);
        if (p == a + b)
        {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else score = score;
        if (q == c - d)
        {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else score = score;
        if (r == g * f)
        {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else score = score;

    }
```

Comment: You're likely giving a non-number string to `Parse`. You'll need to clean/check the input before parsing it, or catch the exception.

Comment: What is the content of `textBoxOne.Text`, `textBoxTwo.Text` and `TextBoxThree.Text` when the code runs?

Comment: please add the language tag

Comment: @TZHX User may input an answer of each formula in those text-boxes.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc okay I did

Comment: @Carcigenicate what do you mean by "clean the input"? Should I delete the content of text-box?

Comment: @Wataru I originally meant to trim any whitespace that the user may have accidentally entered, but ya, you could just wipe the text box on bad input and tell them to read write it.

Comment: @Wataru And he meant the language of the code, not your language. What is this code? C#?

Comment: @Carcigenicate finally I realized, it's C#.

Comment: @Wataru And as TZHX said, show the values of the text boxes that you're trying to parse.

Comment: Silly question...how can the user have correct answers in the textboxes, when the random values are not put into the labels yet?!  Perhaps you need a "Start" button AND an "Answer" button?

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are intending to convert strings or any object to value types like (double, int, long, boolean) you need to check and make sure the string is number.Of course this will be challenging and tedious work to do. Luckly C# offers some nifty conversion methods that doesn't fire exceptions as well.

```
int intValue = 0 ;
int.TryParse(someString,out intValue);
```

I assume the most problematic lines in your code is those three.

```
int p = int.Parse(textBoxOne.Text);
int q = int.Parse(textBoxTwo.Text);
int r = int.Parse(textBoxThree.Text);
```

Since they don't have a check mechanisim to see if the passed value is numeric or not.

So i would suggest to convert those values in the following manner:

```
int p=0 ;
int q=0;
int r=0 ;
int.TryParse(textBoxOne.Text,out p);
int.Parse(textBoxTwo.Text,out q);
int.Parse(textBoxThree.Text, out r);
```